# IndexOf not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, compare, indexof

I am completing a fairly complicated process in node and for it to work properly I need to compare the value of a key in an object to an array. I have checked to make sure I have no async issues and am simply using a indexOf to get the index of the object's key in the array. I have checked the typeof each item and both return "object" "object". Here is an example check that I am making.

```
var cID = [55cebe83d0b3d];

var item = { _id: 55cebe83d0b377d,
  _client: 55cebe83d0b3d,
  institution_type: 'test' }

var cIndex = cID.indexOf(item._client)
```

and then cIndex always equals -1 regardless of it really exists within cID. If I console log item._client it is 55cebe83d0b3d which is exactly what is stored within cID but still returns -1. Any ideas? I also have the data coming from MongoDB and the data is going through body-parser before hitting this function.

Comment: did you try turning your hex number into hex string ? I mean `'5cebe83d0b377d'` instead of `5cebe83d0b377d`

Comment: Why are those values not strings? https://jsbin.com/nesoxejize/edit?js,console

Comment: Either use strings, or prefix the hex-values with `0x`

Comment: The values are coming in from a remote db and were not saved as strings, I have no control over the source data.

Comment: I didn't literally mean the function was incorrect of course its user error, computers don't make mistakes but how else would I word my title to get the point across that I am having indexOf issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that hex numbers are not js-native. Turn them into hex strings. *E.g.* '5cebe83d0b377d' instead of 5cebe83d0b377d.

#### Update

Mea culpa, see Hiyper's comment.

Comment: Hex numbers are js native, but they must be prefixed with `0x`

Comment: Wow I made such a dumb mistake, I attempted to do this earlier by calling String() on the comparison but I just realized I have previously only called String() on one set of hex numbers as opposed to both; long story short I just called String() on both ends and it works perfectly now. Thank you!